# Spring boot is not using two auth methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have an API using Spring boot that previously it would use two auth methods, API KEY and JWT, it was working but suddenly it stopped. I didn't change anything but I can't fix it.

```
import br.rutiquewiski.HealthBridge.infra.security.configuration.api_key.KeySecurityFilter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiKeySecurityConfiguration {

        //Api key auth, any endpoint with key in the url uses authentication with api key instead of the jwt token

        @Autowired
        private KeySecurityFilter keySecurityFilter;

        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain apiKeySecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
            return httpSecurity
                    .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                    .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                                auth.requestMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/swagger-ui/**").permitAll();
                                auth.requestMatchers( AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/api/key/**") ).authenticated();
                            }
                    )
                    .addFilterBefore(keySecurityFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
            return  authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
        }

    }

    @EnableWebSecurity
    @Configuration
    @Order(2)  //This annotation sets this configuration to be the second one in the auth order
    public static class StandardSecurityConfiguration {

        //Regular token auth

        @Autowired
        private TokenSecurityFilter tokenSecurityFilter;

        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain tokenSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
            return httpSecurity.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                    .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                        auth.requestMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/swagger-ui/**").permitAll();
                        auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                    })
                    .addFilterBefore(tokenSecurityFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager2(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
            return  authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
        }

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }

    }

}
```

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>br.rutiquewiski</groupId>
    <artifactId>HealthBridge</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>HealthBridge</name>
    <description>API project por health care system</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-mysql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have tried every simple solution. Currently, if the api key auth config is not commented, the other one doesn't work, if I comment the api key config then the jwt works. I have tried changing the order already

Comment: Change value in @Order annotation for the first authorization configuration, You have duplicated @Order(2)

Comment: Sorry, it was not duplicated, that is not the problem, I just put 2 on both on accident before copying and pasting here

Comment: why have you built a custom JWTfilter and not using the built in JWT features that spring security already has built in

Comment: It's just how I learned how to do it, but do you think that this may be connected to the problem?

Comment: No, sorry, but thank you for trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed by changing the way the two methods are implemented, putting both of them in the same class and using SecuirtyMatcher().

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

@Autowired
private KeySecurityFilter keySecurityFilter;

@Autowired
private TokenSecurityFilter tokenSecurityFilter;

@Bean
@Order(1)
public SecurityFilterChain apiKeySecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    return httpSecurity
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .securityMatcher("/api/key/**")
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {auth.anyRequest().authenticated();})
            .addFilterBefore(keySecurityFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .build();
}

@Bean
@Order(2)
public SecurityFilterChain tokenSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    return httpSecurity
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .securityMatcher("/")
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {auth.anyRequest().authenticated();})
            .addFilterBefore(tokenSecurityFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
    return  authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you, you're the best software developer I have ever met.